# Number data is not binding in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, data-binding

While working on a spring MVC based project I am trying to bind data from JSP to model.

While the string data is binding perfectly for some reason the number data is not binding at all.

I have checked the parameter name it's same in POJO and JSP

Below is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/investor-signup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String registration(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("investor", new InvestorRegister());
        return "investor-signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/investor-signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("investor") InvestorRegister investor, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        System.out.println(investor.getFULL_NAME());
        System.out.println(investor.getMOB_NO());

        investorRegisterService.save(investor);
        return "redirect:/login";
    }
```

Below is my JSP code

```
<form:form method="post" action="investor-signup"
        modelAttribute="investor" id="contact-form"
        style="padding-top: 40px;" role="form" class="formcss" align="left">    

        <div class="controls">    
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">    
                        <div class="col-md-2 ">
                            <label for="user_name">Full Name *</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10 p0">
                            <input id="user_name" type="text" name="FULL_NAME" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Full Name is required.">
                        </div>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label for="user_mobile">Mobile *</label>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="col-md-6 ">
                            <input id="user_mobile" type="number" name="MOB_NO" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Mobile No is required.">
                        </div>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>              

            <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Register">
            </div>    

        </div>    
    </form:form>
```

Below is my model POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "InvestorRegister")
public class InvestorRegister {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "IID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int ID;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "FULL_NAME")
    private String FULL_NAME;

    @Column(name = "MOB_NO")
    private int MOB_NO;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }    
    public void setID(int iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }

    public String getFULL_NAME() {
        return FULL_NAME;
    }    
    public void setFULL_NAME(String fULL_NAME) {
        FULL_NAME = fULL_NAME;
    }

    public int getMOB_NO() {
        return MOB_NO;
    }    
    public void setMOB_NO(int mOB_NO) {
        MOB_NO = mOB_NO;
    }
}
```

While the string data is binding perfectly for some reason the number data is not binding at all

I have checked the parameter name it's same in POJO and JSP

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Wrapper `Integer` instead of `int`.

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "IID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer ID;
```

Also I would suggest to use naming convention standards. Instead of ID declare id or most preferred as investorRegisterId.

After changing from `int` to `Integer` please regenerate the getter/setters for the same.

Your actual issue is failing on the concept of Java auto-boxing/unboxing.

Comment: The problem is not with id(it's going to populated by the database at the time of commit) but rather with data binding with JSP. While text data is properly binding but the numeric data is not binding at all

Answer (score 3):

@abhi314, Have you just tried by extracting field separately ? 
I mean have you tried any of these just to check value comes from view side or not?

```
public String registration(@RequestParam("FULL_NAME") String FULL_NAME, @RequestParam("MOB_NO") int MOB_NO) {
    //check value comes or not 
}
```

OR

```
public String registration(@RequestBody InvestorRegister  ir) {
    //check value comes or not 
}
```

Please do let me know if you get value or not by checking this way

Comment: In response you receive that field ? I mean have you checked in POSTMAN or browser ?

Comment: this is not a API call, rather a JSP to java binding of object via spring MVC

Comment: Yes,it is ok but you can check that in browser no after submitting your form using developer tools--> Network tab?

Comment: I am either getting 'malformed request' or 'unsupported media type' exception by above methods

Comment: Can you please provide its screenshot ? of response in browser console ? it would give me clear idea